# How to find out status of a job (scheduled with at)

Tags: scheduled

How can I find out the status of a job scheduled with `at`?

Comment: Maybe you can explain what "AT" is, the version you are using etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `atq` command. See `man at` for more information.